# Do not send mass mail from PHP SMTP

Tags: php, smtp

I have create a PHP mass mail function but it is not working. When I submit the text it is showing success message but when I check my email inbox and spam folders there has no email. Can you tell me the right way and what is the problem in my code?

From config file:

```
define("EMAIL_USE_SMTP", true);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_HOST", "ssl://example.com");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH", true);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME", "support@example.com");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD", "*******");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_PORT", 465);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION", "ssl");
```

This is the mass mail:

```php
<?php if($page == "mass_mail") { ?>

<div class="head_title">Mass-Mail</div>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit_new'])) {

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$body = $_POST['body'];

$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_active = 1");

$x = 0;

while($queue = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {

$mail = new PHPMailer();

if(EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
if(defined(EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION)) {
$mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
}

$mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
$mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
$mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
} else {
$mail->IsMail();
}

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->do_debug = 0;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = $queue['user_email'];
$mail->AddAddress($address);
$mail->Send();

$x = $x + 1;

}

echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
Email sent to ' . $x . ' users!
</div>';

}

echo '<form action="" method="post">';

echo '<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="What\'s the subject?" class="form-control">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Your message to the users" rows="6"></textarea>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit_new" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">';
echo '</form>';

?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following can be the possible issues:

**1. Mail Port:** Mail port differs with Mail providers. For Gmail try the port 587

**2. SMTP Encryption:** SMTP Secure varies with Mail providers. For Gmail try $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'. Some SMTP servers block connections. Some SMTP servers don't support SSL (or TLS) connections.

**3. Less Secure App:** Allow access from less secure apps. (For e.g. Gmail, Yahoo)